# which software to use to make the rules's game?

Tags: game-development

I begin to write rules of my game on *Word*, but there is something better ? to manage images, backgrounds... etc ?

**how are the rules of professional games created ?**

Comment: I believe Adobe's *InDesign* is the most popular page layout editor. Images are created and touched up in image editing and composition software, of which Adobe's *Photoshop* is the surely most popular. There are other commercial and open-source competitors.

Comment: Yes, InDesign is standard. No offense, but I would only go to this effort if (1) you are determined to pay for a print run out of pocket, and (2) you are an experienced graphic designer. Pitch to a publisher or hire a rulebook creator if not.

Comment: You may want to check out graphic design as they might be able to provide some better help though I am not sure if it would be on topic or not (note this is not saying anything about not asking it here just that you might get better help there). https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

As a fellow aspiring Game Designer, I stick with word or excel for initial content.  Use anything you are familiar with, as content is the only thing you should be worried about.  Unless you plan to self publish, publishers are going to scrap your design for something that they'll get professionally made.  If you do self publish, then I recommend sending it to a professional designer with experience in tabletop games.  Also, you can post to sites like Board Game Designer Forum for peer review by published game designers.  (https://www.bgdf.com/)  There are a ton of articles and advice out there on layout, content and form.  Here are a few:

https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/405444/rule-book-writing

https://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/3277179

http://www.leagueofgamemakers.com/?s=write+rules

Best of luck on your game design!